# GStreamer | How to force deinterlacing of progressive video

Tags: video, gstreamer, ntsc

I am receiving a H.264 progressive video stream which I need to decode and display.

However, the actual images that were encoded are interlaced and the two fields were combined / interleaved before being encoded to produce a pseudo-progressive image (with comb artefacts when displayed).

line 0: even field line 0
line 1: odd field line 0
line 2: even field line 1
line 3: odd field line 1
etc.

On the receiver end, as far as GStreamer is concerned, this is progressive video.

I need to apply a deinterlacing filter before the display to not have the typical 'comb' artefact.

However, since as far as the receiver is concerned this is progressive video, the deinterlace element does not work.

How can I 'tell' GStreamer that the video is fact in the interlaced / interleaved format described above such that deinterlace will correctly filter it?

Can I do it from a pad probe? Must I write an element somehow?

This [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/interlaced-video.html#) mentions 'INTERLEAVED' and states: "If the video info interlace mode is "interleaved", then the buffer is plain interlaced."

What is 'interleaved' video exactly? Is it the case I described above (instead of the fields being one after the other in memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deinterlace` has a property `mode`. Set `mode=interlaced` to force deinterlacing.

Comment: Correct, and it does apply an algo, but it does not know that the fields are interlavesd. Any idea how to tell it?

Comment: For future ref, I was overthinking it. It looks like the default is for the data to be interleaved (a.k.a. weaved), and not for the fields to be separated at the top and bottom of the buffer as I thought. So forcing deinerlace on an interleaved image works. Thanks!